# Extract href with particular text

Tags: jquery, filter, siebel

I have several a tags being generated dynamically in a enterprise application like below

```
<a href='JavaScript:SWESubmitForm(document.SWEForm1_0,s_1,"s_1_1_1_0","1-SXPINW")' onclick='Edit_SList__0__Control__Renew_SPO__onclick(null, "s_1_1_1_0")'  tabindex=2997  id='s_1_1_1_0'>Renew PO</a>
<a href='JavaScript:SWESubmitForm(document.SWEForm1_0,s_2,"s_1_1_4_0","1-SXP9NW")' onclick='Edit_SList__0__Control__XRXAddFunds__onclick(null, "s_1_1_4_0")'  tabindex=2997  id='s_1_1_4_0'>Add Funds</a>
```

I have following jQuery code to extract unique value identifying the record from tag

```
var href = $('a[href*="SWESubmitForm"]').attr('href');
var rowId = "";
    if( href != ""){
        hrefAr =  href.split('","');
        rowId = hrefAr[hrefAr.length - 1];
        rowId = rowId.substr(0,(rowId.length - 2));
    }
```

The above code gives me the value **1-SXPINW** 
but I need to get value **1-SXP9NW** (2nd link and there could several links on one page).
I need to add filter for the text basically retrieve only the value for the link with particular text such as "Add Funds".

I know it is possible to use each and add if statement to check text but I would like to do it through filter.

Please help!!!

**EDIT:**

I think I didn't explain the problem properly. I need to setup filter in such a way that

```
if (text within a tag == "Add Funds") then get the value of ID within href attribute
```

I would like setup my filter based on the text() within a tag. I hope it clarifies the problem a bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the element you want.. If there is two of them just use .eq() since it returns all elements that match your selector- .eq will return a jquery object

```
var href = $('a[href*="SWESubmitForm"]').eq(1).attr('href'); // <-
```

or convert it to dom element

```
var href = $('a[href*="SWESubmitForm"]')[1].href;
```

Also since you have an `ID` you can just select the one you want with the `ID` selector

```
var href = $('#s_1_1_4_0').attr('href');
```

Or if there's too many and you need to find the one with 9NW.. just use indexOf in your check

```
$('a[href*="SWESubmitForm"]').each(function(){
     var rowId = ""; 
     if(this.href.indexOf('1-SXP9NW') > -1){ // <-- use indexOf to see if href contains the string                  
         hrefAr =  this.href.split('","');
         rowId = hrefAr[hrefAr.length - 1];
         rowId = rowId.substr(0,(rowId.length - 2));    
     }
});
```

With filter function

```
var href = $('a[href*="SWESubmitForm"]').filter(function(){
         return this.href.indexOf('1-SXP9NW') > -1;
}).attr('href');
```

After all this.. Why don't you just use this selector?

```
$('a[href*="1-SXP9NW"]')
```

**EDIT:**

If `Add Funds` is static.. then use the [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector

```
var href = $('a:contains("Add Funds")').attr('href');
```

Comment: As I said they are dynamically generated and there can be several on one page and there sequence can change over time. So I cannot base my solution on sequence. I have to ensure that I get value for tag with particular text.

Comment: @user1017268  I updated my answer with a loop.. that will search for the element which contains `1-SXP9NW` in the href

Comment: @user1017268 I updated my answers with a few more ways to get the element you want

Comment: Actually the row id's are generated dynamically so the value 1-SXP9NW will change with each request. The only thing static is the text within the a tag such "Add Funds". So I need to check the text within the <a> tag get the id value that was generated dynamically. I cannot hardcode this id value.

Comment: @user1017268  You can use the `:contains()` selector then..  its in the last update of my answer

Comment: Yup, that what I was looking for, contains did the trick. Marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()` to loop through your links and extract the value you need from the href attribute.

```
$('a[href*="SWESubmitForm"]').each(function() {
    var rowId = "";
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (href != "") {
        hrefAr = href.split('","');
        rowId = hrefAr[hrefAr.length - 1];
        rowId = rowId.substr(0, (rowId.length - 2));
        console.log(rowId);
    }
});​
```

Comment: is not possible to use filter to add the text condition in it.. so I don't have to run the loop around it???

Comment: You should be able use .filter() in place of .each() here. I wasn't sure what you were doing with the data you got back so I stuck with each.